# JavaScript weird assignment code

Tags: javascript

I found this line of code in a project and I couldn't under

```
return d.isPointInside(a, b) ? (console.log("runned"), c = !0, !1) : void 0
```

And I couldn't understand the part:

```
(console.log("runned"), c = !0, !1)
```

The word "runned" should be displayed in the browser's console, But need some help to understand the rest.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comma_operator) may help to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some type juggeling

```
!0 === true
!1 === false
void 0 === undefined
```

The result with some longer words:

```
(console.log("runned"), c = true, false);
```

The complete return statement reads as following, without use of the [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
if (d.isPointInside(a, b)) {
    console.log("runned");
    c = true;
    return false;
} else {
    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, these responses were very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The commas just create a sequence, so ultimately this statement will return !1 which is false.  The code is exploiting the sequence syntax to produce a byproduct of outputting to console and setting a variable.

It's similar to:

var a,b,c;

Which declares variables but doesn't do anything with them.  This is equally valid:

var a=7,b=someComplexCalculation(),c;

!1 is false, and is kind of useless, but in JavaScript this is a useful form because it forces type to be Boolean.  When developing, it may be useful to change !1 to !a, which is guaranteed to return a Boolean value.

The last value of the sequence completes the statement, and acts as the return value.

So:

X=(3, Math.sqrt(2), "something");

Will set X="something"

Comment: *`this statement will return !1 which is false`*  you should expand on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, the code is using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in JavaScript that evaluate everything but only return the last element. For example `var a = 1, 2, 3;` will always be equal to 3 because only the last item gets returned.

With this in mind, let's look at the piece of code you didn't understand:

```
(console.log("runned"), c = !0, !1)
```

Due to the comma operator, this breaks up into three expressions that will be evaluated in a sequence:

```
console.log("runned")
```

Will print the given word in the console.

```
c = !0
```

Will assign the value of `true` to the variable `c`. This is because zero is a falsey value which when converted to the opposite using the not operator `!` produces `true`.

```
`!1`
```

Finally the result of this expression will be returned from the entire section inside the brackets. Similar to the above, this uses the fact that `1` is a truthy value, so `!1` will yield `false`.

So, taken as a whole, the code will print, assign a value, and return a value all in one line.

Given the syntax and the variables used, my assumption is that this is minified code. Minification uses the language rules in a similar manner in order to reduce the amount of characters used. In partucular `!0` and `!1` are very common replacements of `true` and `false` because they latter are at least half the length.